# How to export mvc table data to excel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, export-to-excel

I have View that contains some text box and dropdowns, Submit button and partial page. When i clicked on submit button, Partial page will load with data in table format.

Now i want a feature that, when i clicked on Export button the data in Partial page (Data contains in Table) should be exported to excel document.

I have Tried to do so by adding export submit button in partial page as below...

```
<input type="submit" value="Export" id="btnExport" />
```

In controller :

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
{
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
return View();
}
```

But its exporting All page details. i.e, Excel is showing all the textbox, dropdown, submit buttons, and table.

I just want table data. How do i get only table data. Please somebody help me with this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could place the table inside a partial and then render only the partial when exporting to Excel:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    return PartialView("_Table");
}
```

Comment: This worked for me using IE, but in Chrome it won't work without adding Content-Disposition

Comment: @RobertBrooker: Can you elaborate? What value did you give to `Content-Disposition` to make it work in Chrome?

Comment: I think from memory we had Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ExcelFile.xls